# Does Iran allow promotion of Sunni in their country?

Tags: religion, religious-law

As far as I know Iran officially hold Twelver Shiism as the state religion.

With that saying, does Iranian law prohibit people (especially in massive political/social movement) that promotes practices of Sunni?

Comment: Well, Zoroastrians, Jews, and Christians are officially recognized and protected. Vast numbers of Kurds are Yarsan. OTOH, Baha'i still get the short end of the stick, and Mandaeans are persecuted. What do you mean by "promote"?

Comment: Inviting other to practices of Sunni through preaching, seminary, debate, etc